# Spiral Knights will not start

Tags: technical-issues, spiral-knights

I've recently gotten a new laptop, and am attempting to play Spiral Knights on it, however the game simply will not load. Every time I attempt to start it, I get a "This game is currently unavailable, please try again at another time" error. I've tried verifying the integrity of the game cache, deleting the local content and reinstalling, rebooting my computer... nothing works. Since this has persisted for a few days, I doubt it's on steam's end, is there any fix for this?

Comment: is your firewall open for whatever port spiral knights needs?  Also, it helps if you post your OS (I'm assuming windows 7?)  Try running the game as administrator.

Comment: As yx_ said, try running the game as administrator. It looks like the game is having some permission problems.

Comment: I'm using a mac OS X v10.7 and an admin account. I don't think permissions are the problem here.

Comment: Have you tried using the solution posted at the steam forums? -> http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=24544168&postcount=22

Comment: I totally missed that topic, that guy's a genius! Problem solved. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it ASAP.

Comment: this dosent work for me it says no such file or directory but im looking at the folder in my finder right now

Comment: I think the problem might be the last directory. Try entering spiral\ knights at the end instead, or simply cd'ing through the directories one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS X version of the game has some issues with permission handling. The solution is to add the permission via the terminal:

> 1. Open "Terminal.app"
> 2. Type: `cd /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/spiral knights`
> 3. Hit Enter
> 4. Type: chmod +x run.sh
> 5. Hit Enter

Then the game should run normally from steam.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=24544168&postcount=22)

Answer (score 1):

The OS X distribution doesn't give the launch script execute permissions [(source)](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=24544168&postcount=22).

To fix, in Terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/spiral knights
chmod +x run.sh
```

(If that path doesn't work, try it without the tilde or with "Users/[your username]" instead)

(You must be running as superuser to do this. Use `sudo chmod +x run.sh` if you're not an admin.)